# Express.js + Passport.js + no-ip.org issue: dynamic ip server user authentication keeps getting reset

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, session-timeout, passport.js

I've tried searching far and wide for a solution to this. The app works properly when run as localhost keeping users authenticated for an extended period. But when I run it on my server  and log in it's like the connection gets reset after a short while and I am forced to log in again.

My app (has more dependencies but I guess these are of most relevance):

- ExpressJS ver. 3.0.0rc4
- PassportJS ver. 0.1.15

My Server:

- Runs the app using forever.js
- Has to reconnect to the network it's on using VPN.
- To provide a stable entrypoint I use [noip.com](http://www.noip.com/) which through a client installed on the computer is able to make sure that my free domain always points to my server's ip.

Most likely the issue has something to do with no-ip.org and the dynamic ip. Any ideas?

Pasting the app config code as well:

```
app.configure ->
  app.set "port", process.env.PORT or 8080
  app.set "views", __dirname + "/views"
  app.set "view engine", "jade"
  app.locals.compileDebug = false #Made jade a little more compact
  app.use express.favicon()
  # app.use express.logger("tiny")
  app.use express.logger("dev")
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use express.methodOverride()
  app.use express.cookieParser("awesome unicorns")
  app.use express.session(
    secret: "awesome unicorns"
    cookie:
      maxAge: 2592000000
  )
  app.use flash()
  app.use passport.initialize()
  app.use passport.session()
  app.use app.router
  app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))
```

**Update:**

I updated the code as adviced by commenter RobertKlep, and revisited my page. This time I compared the session cookie when running the app as localhost versus on the server. The localhost  And the server's cookie was not being correctly set. The problem [might be related to this discussion](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747387).

**Second update plus final solution**

Problem solved! Turns out I had hidden node processes running which prevented the app from being properly updated. Furthermore since the server was listening on port 80, a conflict was raised because I had not configured socket.io to listen to a different port using `app.listen(81);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
app.use express.session(
  secret: "awesome unicorns"
  maxAge:
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)
)
```

`maxAge` isn't an argument for `express.session`, I think you meant `cookie` there:

```
app.use express.session(
  secret : ...
  cookie :
    expires : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)
)
```

Also, if used like that, the expiry date is evaluated just once: at the startup of your application. So after an hour of running the application, any new sessions will expire immediately.

Use `maxAge` instead, which sets the expiry relative to the moment of creating the session:

```
app.use express.session(
  secret : ...
  cookie :
    maxAge : 3600000
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out and report back by tomorrow. :)

Comment: Was able to get some progress, but the problem still persists. Updated my question with more info.

Comment: Session cookie expiry now seems to be 1 minute (response timestamp is `10:00:16`, cookie expiry timestamp is `10:01:16`), which seems odd (it's not a random value and also not the value you set with `maxAge`; could there be a part of your app that uses `res.cookie()`? I don't any of the middleware you mention will modify cookies like that)

Comment: Problem solved, updated question with comments on the final solution.  Thanks for the help!